# SQL Case Statement or should I use SQL and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms, mysqli, case-statement

I want to make it so if you press a button, it changes the value from 0 to 1, or if the value is 1, then 1 to 0.

0 ----> 1
1 ----> 0

I want to limit the things in an array that can have a value of 1 to 10 things.

Ex: favorites[]

My goal is to be able to add items to a collection with a click of a button, and using the same button, take them off while having a limit of 10.

Should I use JS to limit, or can I use LIMIT in my sql to make that happen?
How would I accomplish this?

Right now this is what I have:

```
SELECT  fav FROM u_collection WHEN username = "' . $username. '" 
  CASE 
     WHEN fav =  0 THEN fav = 1
     WHEN fav =  1 THEN fav = 0
     ELSE fav = 0
```

And this is what more form more or less ends up looking like, to give you an idea: 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your use case exactly, but if you want to have a dynamic list, then querying SQL on every click doesn't sound right. 
I would have all the implementation client-side in JS. So, you can load up an array from SQL once during initialization and then have full control over user actions and a Save button so that changes can be pushed to the database.
Hope that helps.